# iOS - Trigger Local Notification when message is received

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilocalnotification, nsnotificationcenter

I'm building an app that allows its users to send each other messages. When a new message is received, it appears in the current user's Table view. I want my app to send the current user a notification when a new message arrives. Does anyone know how I might go about doing this?

I have notifications set up in my AppDelegate already:

**appdelegate.m**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:nil]];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
```

and I know the below code will allow me to fire a notification at a specified time (e.g. set by a picker):

```
 // Get the current date
    NSDate *pickerDate = [self.datePicker date];

    // Schedule the notification
    UILocalNotification* localNotification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    localNotification.fireDate = pickerDate;
    localNotification.alertBody = self.itemText.text;
    localNotification.alertAction = @"You are being notified!";
    localNotification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];
    localNotification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] applicationIconBadgeNumber] + 1;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:localNotification];

    // Request to reload table view data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"reloadData" object:self];

    // Dismiss the view controller
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

How do I make a notification occur however when a new message is posted to the server (and appears in the tableview) for the logged in user?

Comment: You need to send a push notification to your app when there is a new message. You can either have the push notification displayed directly or you can send a "silent" notification and use this to generate a local notification

Comment: Hi @Paulw11 - I've successfully setup Push Notifications (using this tutorial: https://www.raywenderlich.com/123862/push-notifications-tutorial) - I'm just not sure how to make it trigger only when a new message is posted? Right now I'm triggering them manually from my Terminal

Comment: You typically handle that from your server side, although you can have your sending app instance do it, but that is a lot less preferable.

Comment: No, you don't need to set up push notifications. You can use a local notification if your app receives these messages when it's running. You need to implement the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` method

Comment: @DuncanC How?! Lol. Yes these notifications are happening while the app is running; but what block of code could I use to say, e.g. "When new message is received, trigger notification X"

Comment: How do you know you have received a message from the server? You make it sound like you have an existing method that gets called when a message comes in. Assuming that's true, in that method you'd trigger a local notification.

Comment: @BlairWarner do you want to trigger the notification when the app is running on screen or when the app is in the background? I assumed the second because when the app is running on screen, surely the user would just see the new message

Comment: @Paulw11 Ahh yes, definitely the latter.

Comment: Then that is why you need push notifications.  When your app is running in the background it doesn't execute except in response to specific events.  One of those is the receipt of a remote notification (if it is a silent notification) or the user tapping on a notification (if it isn't silent).  Either way, once your app is executing in the background in response to one of these events it can download the new message(s) from the server, update the local data store and notify the user (in the case of the silent notification)

Answer (score 0):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
       UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeBadge|UIUserNotificationTypeSound|UIUserNotificationTypeAlert) categories:nil];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];}
```

If your system is iOS8, you need to register permission.

```
UILocalNotification * notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    NSDate * pushDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:Time];
    if (notification!=nil) {


        notification.fireDate= pushDate;

        notification.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

        notification.repeatInterval = kCFCalendarUnitDay;

        notification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;

        notification.alertBody = @"Time O.K!";
        NSLog(@"Ready");

        notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;
        //notification.applicationIconBadgeNumber = [[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]+1;

        NSDictionary * inforDic = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"name" forKey:@"key"];
        notification.userInfo =inforDic;

        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
    }
```

You can have a try,this code I can successfully use on my device.

Comment: I'm confused - doesn't this do the same as the above posted code (only notify if a specific time is provided)?

Comment: You can use a timer to trigger local notification when specific time.